# How to add list of files to clipboard for cutting

Tags: c#, wpf, clipboard

I've found [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14059/Drag-and-drop-cut-copy-and-paste-files-with-Window) on Code Project that shows how to add a list of files (paths) to the clipboard and flag it for moving instead of copying.
The method used is shown in multiple articles across the internet and is said to be working, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I'm on Windows 8.1 (64 bit). After I cut a few files from my list and try to paste the files somewhere in Explorer, I just hear a ding and nothing happens.
Copying files works though.

Here's what I have:

```
StringCollection paths = new StringCollection();
foreach (FileInformation file in lbxFoundFiles.SelectedItems)
{
    paths.Add(file.FileInf.FullName);
}

IDataObject data = new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, paths);
MemoryStream memo = new MemoryStream(4);
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 2, 0, 0, 0 };
memo.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
data.SetData("Preferred DropEffect", memo);
Clipboard.SetDataObject(data);
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've passed to `DataObject` constructor wrong data. Do it in such way:

```
byte[] moveEffect = { 2, 0, 0, 0 };
MemoryStream dropEffect = new MemoryStream();
dropEffect.Write(moveEffect, 0, moveEffect.Length);

StringCollection filestToCut = new StringCollection {"D:\\test.txt"};
DataObject data = new DataObject("Preferred DropEffect", dropEffect);
data.SetFileDropList(filestToCut);

//or execute default constructor and uncomment line below:
//data.SetData("Preferred DropEffect", dropEffect);

Clipboard.Clear();
Clipboard.SetDataObject(data, true);
```

Comment: I've tried them all, but this one did it!
Thanks a lot.